# Python - Trying to use pandas to skip n rows until I reach a specific record

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Basically my problem is that I'm trying to create a code that will use Pandas to skip x amount of rows until it reaches a row containing records named `departmentName` and `departmentID`. This has been troubling for me because nearly all the questions I've seen have asked about how to skip a specified number of rows but with this issue, there is no specified amount of rows that will be skipped, it could be any amount. So I need a formula that will automatically adapt to this issue. Any ideas?

| Unamed_1 | Unamed_2 |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |
| Credits |  |
| 1 | Math |
| 2 | Computer Science |
| 3 | History |
| 4 | Deep Learning |

This what I have done so far:

```
for index_1, row_1 in df_cmd.iterrows():
    if row_1.notnull().all():
```

I want to get the name of the row

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas: Get index of rows which column matches certain value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800169/python-pandas-get-index-of-rows-which-column-matches-certain-value)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say that I perfectly understand what you mean but I recommend you to check the "edit part" of this question.
[pandas import specific part of table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68512925/import-a-dynamic-table-cell-value-into-python-code)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you have in mind, but maybe you should try

```
df.loc[['departmentName']]
```

> I want to get the name of the row

do you mean the **index**? you said the name of the row yourself

Answer (score 0):

If I can get you right.

Lets take some df as example:

```
col2 = ["Math",
"Computer Science",
"History",
"Deep Learning",
"departmentName",
"departmentID",
"More",
"And more",
"And even more"]

test = pd.DataFrame(col2, columns = ["Dep"])
```

Than this way you can get a needed index:

```
index = test.index[test["Dep"] == "departmentName"][0]
```

And that way you get everything after the row with that index:

```
test.iloc[index:]
```

Watch out if there will be more than 1 row with that value.